# Wix XML Error - The Component/@Directory attribute cannot be specified when the Component element is nested underneath a Directory element

Tags: wix, wix3.6

First time doing some Wix practice, so im completely new to it.

Here is my short script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="SampleMSI" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Nunya" UpgradeCode="b2c39f9b-1de1-433e-bc59-a3548cc531b9">

        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Description="Installs Signout Utility" Keywords="Practice,Signout,Utility,MSI,Installer" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SampleMSI" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SampleMSI" />
         <Directory Id="APPFOLDER" Name="APPDir" >
         </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="CMP_ADispOCX"
              Guid="5E23B839-35CA-480E-8AFC-2E914BA8E32A"
              Directory="INSTALLLOCATION">
      <File Id="FILE_ADispocx"
              Source="ADisp.ocx"
              KeyPath="yes" />
        </Component>
     <Component Id="CMP_Abtn32ocx"
              Guid="98B357F2-C295-4019-A878-885E56AA3BF3"
              Directory="INSTALLLOCATION">
      <File Id="FILE_Abtn32a20ocx"
              Source="btn32a20.ocx"
              KeyPath="yes" />
        </Component>
   </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I just wanted to make sure they are going to the same folder, basic installation check. (it is my first time)

I get this error however:
Error   2   The Component/@Directory attribute cannot be specified when the Component element is nested underneath a Directory element.

I get it twice for each component id I have.

Am I missing something? Im using Wix 3.6 A Developers Guide for reference.

edit: Side question......how do I specify an exact path? like C:\Herp\Derp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify the directory of a Component if you did so already in the ComponentGroup element.  Remove the Directory attribute in both Components elements in your fragment.

Change your code to this

```
    <Fragment>
            <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
          <Component Id="CMP_ADispOCX"
                  Guid="5E23B839-35CA-480E-8AFC-2E914BA8E32A">

          <File Id="FILE_ADispocx"
                  Source="ADisp.ocx"
                  KeyPath="yes" />
            </Component>
         <Component Id="CMP_Abtn32ocx"
                  Guid="98B357F2-C295-4019-A878-885E56AA3BF3">

          <File Id="FILE_Abtn32a20ocx"
                  Source="btn32a20.ocx"
                  KeyPath="yes" />
            </Component>
       </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```